# Android Studio : Unfortunately the app has stopped. I have found a lot of errors in the LayoutInflator.java

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

As per the comments I have added the ActivityMain.xml file below the logcat. I am trying to build a simple app with a floating action bar in it.  I don't know where I have made the mistake.

The following is the message in the logcat.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.lenovo.makersbuilders5, PID: 3767
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lenovo.makersbuilders5/com.example.lenovo.makersbuilders5.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
     at com.example.lenovo.makersbuilders5.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
     at com.example.lenovo.makersbuilders5.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
     at com.example.lenovo.makersbuilders5.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable()' on a null object reference
     at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$ChildDrawable.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:1723)
     at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$LayerState.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:1792)
     at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable$RippleState.<init>(RippleDrawable.java:982)
     at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState(RippleDrawable.java:973)
     at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState(RippleDrawable.java:972)
     at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.mutate(LayerDrawable.java:1652)
     at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.mutate(RippleDrawable.java:959)
     at android.view.View.applyBackgroundTint(View.java:17429)
     at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:17305)
     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.access$001(FloatingActionButton.java:70)
     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$ShadowDelegateImpl.setBackgroundDrawable(FloatingActionButton.java:831)
     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButtonLollipop.setBackgroundDrawable(FloatingActionButtonLollipop.java:71)
     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:181)
    at android.support.des
```

**ActivityMain.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lenovo.makersbuilders5.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_youtube"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="260dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Color2"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_youtube"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_insta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Color3"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_insta"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_fb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Color1"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_facebook"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plussign"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**LayoutInflator.java** Only the part with errors as there is a lot of code!!

```
import com.android.internal.R;

import android.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.annotation.Nullable;

   protected LayoutInflater(LayoutInflater original, Context newContext) {
        mContext = newContext;
        mFactory = original.mFactory;
        mFactory2 = original.mFactory2;
        mPrivateFactory = original.mPrivateFactory;
        setFilter(original.mFilter);
    }

   public View inflate(@LayoutRes int resource, @Nullable ViewGroup root) {
        return inflate(resource, root, root != null);
    }

   public View inflate(XmlPullParser parser, @Nullable ViewGroup root) {
        return inflate(parser, root, root != null);
    }

   public View inflate(@LayoutRes int resource, @Nullable ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot) {
        final Resources res = getContext().getResources();
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "INFLATING from resource: \"" + res.getResourceName(resource) + "\" ("
                    + Integer.toHexString(resource) + ")");
        }

    public View inflate(XmlPullParser parser, @Nullable ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot) {
        synchronized (mConstructorArgs) {
            Trace.traceBegin(Trace.TRACE_TAG_VIEW, "inflate");


                Trace.traceEnd(Trace.TRACE_TAG_VIEW);
            }
```

Comment: put the mainActivity code in the question to better help

Comment: problem in the XML, check the design...

Comment: Post your XML file code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: upload your xml design code

Comment: @BrunoFerreira I have just added it for your reference. Thank you !

Comment: @KrishnaMeena I just did. Please check !! Thankyou

Comment: @Proxytype Please help me in checking it.

Comment: @NidhiPandya okay i just did. thankyou

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto So does that mean I have to make a specific change in my MainActivity.Java file ?

Answer (score 0):

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

this is the exception. I think maybe you not imported design-library;

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
```

or maybe bad attributes

**EDIT UPDATE**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_youtube"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="260dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/Color2"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_youtube"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />
```

Different line from your code is

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/Color2"
    app:elevation="6dp"
```

Comment: 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1' was added to the gradle in the beginning. So it has to be bad attributes but can you help me in where to look exactly?

Comment: com.android.support:appcompat-v25.3.1+ added support for tinting widgets on devices running pre android 5.1 (API Level 21). To make use of it make sure you extend or set the AppCompat Theme and use app:backgroundTint instead of android:backgroundTint.

Also change android:elevation to app:elevation

Comment: I hope that helps. But how exactly should I make that change? Should I type it in 'styles.xml' ? And if so.. what should I type?

Comment: Answer updated. use 'app:' instead of 'android:'. It maybe help you

Comment: but where should I use?

Comment: Just in FloatingActionButtons. Are you cheched the my answer? I updated the answer. Copy my code and replace your FloatingActionButtons. Then check the it is working or not

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot add support `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'`
Just add this dependencies in your gradle file like this

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
}
```

Comment: I already had added the design code line to the dependencies.  Nevertheless i pasted your code over mine and still no change, So what next?